# Assign user to group, Azure AD Graph Api

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on Azure B2C single Signon. I am using:

> Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;

I want to create a function to assign a user to a group, but it is not working:

```
var user = this.aadClient.Users.Where(u => u.SignInNames.Any(n => n.Value == "sss@sss.com"))
                                    .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault() as User;

var group = this.aadClient.Groups.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Equals(role, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                        .Expand(g => g.Members).ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault() as Group;

group.Members.Add(user);
await group.UpdateAsync();
```

both the user and the group are correct.
But I am getting this exception on await group.UpdateAsync():

> The relationship is already tracked by the context.

I have tried to update the context:

```
await this.aadClient.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I am getting the same exception.

Where is the problem in my Code? Any tips could be helpful. thank you!

Comment: I don't know the objectId, I am dealing with display name with the group.

Comment: This case may be helpful to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44115248/ms-graph-api-c-sharp-add-user-to-group

Comment: I have tried it, Reference does not exist on the Group. It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works for me:

```
var group = this.aadClient.Groups.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Equals(role, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                        .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault() as Group;

group.Members.Add(user);
await this.aadClient.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I guess the problem was that the user already has this role.